# UICollectionView loading animation like iphone unlock screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, ios-animations

Does anyone know how to achieve `UICollectionView` loading animation like apple's unlock animation shown below?

[image]

Comment: your question is good,

Comment: see this http://applidium.github.io/ADLivelyCollectionView/

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it is good, but not exactly what I was looking for, I will try to see if I can change it to get what I want, thank you

Comment: You can achieve this by using "Transitions". This http://mathewsanders.com/custom-menu-transitions-in-swift/  will help you but that is in swift so you can get idea of how to do it.